# No module named 'flask_sqlalchemy'

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm use from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy. that code is showing a error in my console
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_sqlalchemy' whereas I have flask-sqlalchemy already install by

pip install flask-sqlalchemy. all code is here

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql://root:@localhost/clean-blog'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Contacts(db.Model):
    srno = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    phone = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)
    message = db.Column(db.String(500), nullable=False)
```

Comment: do you have a virtual-env?